# How to draw a circle on top of an image?

Tags: java, animation, applet

I'm learning how to make java applets, and I'm trying to take an image of an intersection and run a circle across it.  I'm able to import the image and have it displayed in the applet, but the circle won't show on top of it.  I'm just having it start in the top left and go towards the left of the screen.  Any ideas?

`````
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.TextField;

public class App extends Applet implements Runnable{
    int x,y;
    boolean running = true;
    Image background;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8667920279388305018L;

    public void init() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        background = getImage(getCodeBase(), "street.png");
        BackGroundPanel bgp = new BackGroundPanel();
        bgp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        bgp.setBackGroundImage(background);
        setSize(500,500);
        // set the layout of the applet to Border Layout
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // now adding the panel, adds to the center
        // (by default in Border Layout) of the applet
        add(bgp);

    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            ++x;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            repaint();
        }

    }

````}

class BackGroundPanel extends Panel implements ImageObserver {
     /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Image backGround;

     BackGroundPanel() {
          super();
     }

     public void paint(Graphics g) {

          // get the size of this panel (which is the size of the applet),
          // and draw the image
          g.drawImage(getBackGroundImage(), 0, 0,
              (int)getBounds().getWidth(), (int)getBounds().getHeight(), this);
     }

     public void setBackGroundImage(Image backGround) {
          this.backGround = backGround;    
     }

     private Image getBackGroundImage() {
          return backGround;    
     }
}
`````

Comment: you need to draw the image and on top of it the circle

Comment: That's what I'm doing.  It doesn't show up on top of the image.

Comment: you have to do it in one place you are interfering witn the Background block.panel - the panel obstructs  so if you gonna put the panel draw everytning on tha panel (bgd)

Comment: Do you have an explicit example for the code I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw everything in paint and not use the panel:

```
public class App extends Applet implements Runnable{
int x,y;
boolean running = true;
Image background;
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8667920279388305018L;

public void init() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    background = getImage(getCodeBase(), "street.png");
    setSize(500,500);
    // set the layout of the applet to Border Layout
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());


}

@Override
public void start() {
    new Thread(this).start();
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 0,
          (int)getBounds().getWidth(), (int)getBounds().getHeight(), this);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(running) {
        ++x;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        repaint();
    }

}
```

`````
Or if you want the panel you add it and draw everything there - you have to move some stuff to the panel though such as the x, y and the image - and you repaint the panel:


public class App extends Applet implements Runnable{
    boolean running = true;
    BackGroundPanel bgp = new BackGroundPanel();
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8667920279388305018L;

    public void init() {
        bgp.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        bgp.setImage(getImage(getCodeBase(), "street.png"));
        setSize(500,500);
        // set the layout of the applet to Border Layout
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // now adding the panel, adds to the center
        // (by default in Border Layout) of the applet
        add(bgp);

    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            ++bgp.x;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bgp.repaint();
        }

    }

````}


class BackGroundPanel extends Panel implements ImageObserver {
    int x,y;
     /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Image background;

     BackGroundPanel() {
        super();
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
     }

    public void setImage (Image i) {
        background=i;
    }

     public void paint(Graphics g) {

          // get the size of this panel (which is the size of the applet),
          // and draw the image
          g.drawImage(background, 0, 0,
              (int)getBounds().getWidth(), (int)getBounds().getHeight(), this);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100);
     }

     public void setBackGroundImage(Image backGround) {
          this.backGround = backGround;    
     }

     private Image getBackGroundImage() {
          return backGround;    
     }
}
`````

Comment: Thank you so much!!